# Changing The Page URL in OpenCart using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

I have a problem in opencart project. i want to change a url to other using htaccess.

Our link is:-

> http://domain.com/POSextension/index.php?route=pos/login

But i want to display it like:

> http://domain.com/POSextension/pos

how to change it? Plz help me.. :(

Comment: Are both domains `http://pos.domain.com` and `http://domain.com` pointing to same `DocumentRoot` directory?

Comment: yes, these points to same directory

Comment: how to solve it ? @anubhava

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?pos\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(POSextension)/?$ $1/index.php?route=pos/login [L,QSA,NC]
```

**However if `/POSextension/.htaccess` also exists then use this rule:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /POSextension/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?pos\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?route=pos/login [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: That kind of comment is of no use since it doesn't have any other relevant details. Besides this rule definitely works independently but I cannot guess what other rules and htaccess you might have.